# How to merge appsettings.json depending on the selected build configuration in Net Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, configuration, appsettings, .net-core-3.1

I have a Worker Service in Net Core 3.1 that reads Production settings from the `appsettings.json` file and, during development (using the "Debug" build configuration), overwrites `appsettings.json` settings with `appsettings.Development.json`, as expected.

I created a build configuration and publish configuration for our QA environment and I want that the `appsettings.QA.json` file to be merged with `appsettings.json` at build / publish time. But publishing the project only copies `appsettings.json` with the production settings without merging with the settings in the `aspsetting.QA.json` file.

How can I achieve this? I didn't want to copy `appsettings.QA.json` to the QA environment and set `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` to `QA`. I would like not to depend on environment variables in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.Net Core does not merge the files into a physical file. They get merged in memory using such block of code in your Program.cs.

```
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
             .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
             {
                 var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
                 config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                 .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                 
                 config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
             })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

All you need to do is to set the environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT and .net core will automatically take care of it.